# Using declaration in condition part of FOR-loop statement

Tags: c++, for-loop

Reading http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for I find, that *condition* part of `for` loop can be either expression, contextually convertible to `bool`, or *single-variable-declaration with mandatory brace-or-equal initializer* (syntax specification in 6.4/1):

> condition:
>
> - expression
> - type-specifier-seq declarator = assignment-expression

But I have never seen a using of the later in a source code.

**What** is the profitable (in sense of brevity, expressiveness, readability) making use of variable declaration in *condition* part of `for` loop statement **?**

```
for (int i = 0; bool b = i < 5; ++i) {
    // `b` is always convertible to `true` until the end of its scope
} // scope of `i` and `b` ends here
```

Variable declared in *condition* can be only convertible to `true` during whole period of lifetime (scope) if there no side effects influencing on result of convertion to `bool`.

I can imagine only a couple of use cases:

- declaration a variable of class type, having user-defined `operator bool`.
- some kind of changing cv-ref-qualifiers of loop variable:

  ```
  for (int i = 5; int const & j = i; --i) {
      // using of j
  }
  ```

But both of them are very artifical.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All three statements `if`, `for` and `while` can be used in a similar way. Why is this useful? Sometimes it just is. Consider this:

```
Record * GetNextRecord();         // returns null when no more records
Record * GetNextRecordEx(int *);  // as above, but also store signal number

// Process one
if (Record * r = GetNextRecord()) { process(*r); }

// Process all
while (Record * r = GetNextRecord()) { process(*r); }

// Process all and also keep some loop-local state
for (int n; Record * r = GetNextRecordEx(&n); )
{
    process(*r);
    notify(n);
}
```

These statements keep all the variables they need at the minimal possible scope. If the declaration form wasn't allowed inside the statement, you would need to declare a variable outside the statement but you would only need it for the duration of the statement. That means you would either leak into too large a scope, or you would need unsightly extra scopes. Allowing the declaration inside the statement offers a convenient syntax, which although rarely useful is very nice to have *when* it is useful.

Perhaps the most common-place use case is in a multiple-dispatch cast situation like this:

```
if (Der1 * p = dynamic_cast<Der1 *>(target)) visit(*p);
else if (Der2 * p = dynamic_cast<Der2 *>(target)) visit(*p);
else if (Der3 * p = dynamic_cast<Der3 *>(target)) visit(*p);
else throw BadDispatch();
```

As an aside: only the `if` statement admits a code path for the case where the condition is false, given in an optional `else` block. Neither `while` nor `for` allow you to consume the result of the boolean check in this way, i.e. there is no `for ... else` or `while ... else` construction in the language.